# Is it drawn? Can I achieve something similar to this by editing image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, image-editing

I think this somehow may be achieved using threshold, but I'm not sure
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you posted is really too small and low resolution to tell you much. There's a much higher res image here. https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a1340517609_10.jpg

If you desaturate it and do a levels adjustment then invert the image it looks somewhat like a line drawing, possibly with a photographic image of a face superimposed, that has been scanned and printed as a monochrome halftone.

[image]

That's about as much as I can tell.  It's often difficult to work out what was done to an image without access to the original - so this is only a guess.

Reverse engineering this, you could find or make a line drawing, convert to greyscale mode, apply the colour halftone filter, then back to rgb colour mode, add an invert adjustment layer, then a hue-saturation adjustment layer, choose the colorize option, and adjust the hue until it's blue, reduce the lightness slider.